# Why do I have to input two duplicate nextLine method in order for spaces to work on printing a String instead of just one duplicate nextLine method?

Tags: java, string, java-8, java.util.scanner, stdout

I was taking a coding challenge in which I was to take an integer, a double, and a string from `stdin` and have this print in `stdout`. The String had to be a String in which had to include more than a singular word, separated by spaces.

When I inputted the code with only a singular `nextLine` method below the line with `nextDouble`, it worked on the challenge website, but didn't work in my editor. Both the site and my editor were using Java 8. I tried to switch between different Java 8 packages in my editor, but it didn't make a difference. What gives?

Normally, from what I gather, you only have to put *one* dummy `nextLine` in order to resolve the Java `nextInt` method not reading newline characters created by hitting "Enter". But in this case, I have to do this *twice*.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {
    private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i = scan.nextInt();

        // Write your code here.
        scan.nextLine();
        double d = scan.nextDouble();
        scan.nextLine();
        scan.nextLine(); //why do I have to include this line in order for spaces to print on my string in stdout?
        String s = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("String: " + s);
        System.out.println("Double: " + d);
        System.out.println("Int: " + i);
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't have to include an extra `scan.nextLine()` if the `String` is supposed to be the next line after the `double`.  The challenge must be expecting an extra blank line between the `double` and the `String`.  As you haven't shown the text of the challenge, it's hard to know why the challenge would expect that.

Comment: It's not the coding challenge that expected the extra next line, I only had one `scan.nextLine()` under the double in the challenge, and it stated it was correct. What tripped me out is that it didn't work properly in IDEA on my local PC.

Comment: I'd be interested to see if anyone else can reproduce this issue.  I know this is an unhelpful thing to say, but this works fine for me, without the extra call.

Comment: You can print the Scanner input right after user enters it?
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        String s = scan.next();
        System.out.println("String: " + s);
        
        double d = scan.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Double: " + d);
        
        int i = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Int: " + i);
    }
}

Comment: Which version of IntelliJ IDEA are you using? It could be a known problem described in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-293951/Console-readLine-skips-input-in-202211

Comment: @dissidenttux this problem came up already with IntelliJ. As Thomas Klager said, it is a known bug in Intellij  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72327807/why-is-the-second-string-returned-from-readline-an-empty-string/72327845#72327845

Comment: Thanks everyone! I thought there was something wrong with my local install. Weird bug. Happy to know it's not my fault, haha.

Answer (score 0):

The `nextDouble()` method only reads in a double. However, whenever the user inputs a number, the user will press the Enter key. This Enter key is essentially the newline character (`\n`) and is ignored by the `nextDouble()` method as it is not a double. We say that the `nextDouble()` method does not consume the newline character.

Whenever you use the `nextLine()` method after the `nextDouble()` method, you should always have an additional `nextLine()` method to consume the previous newline character.